# Websever Setup Troubleshooting

Tags: dns, webserver, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to setup a web server and I'm not sure where to proceed troubleshooting. Here's where I am at:

1. I installed apache
2. I pointed my domain to afraid.org (Dynamic DNS service) and installed their software on the server
3. Enabled port forwarding on my router for HTTP (80) VNC (5500), SSH (22). As well as enabled DMZ host for the server. My router is a Westell 7500.

The server hosts on the local network appropriately using both the the server's IP or my domain -- which I believe indicates the Dynamic DNS is working. However I cannot access the website on another network.

Here are the contents for my ports.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80  

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>  
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change  
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>  
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not  
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.  
    Listen 443  
</IfModule>  

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>  
    Listen 443  
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check configuration of iptables. And also check if virtual server is properly configured to accept connections from outside.

Comment: It doesn't appear iptables is installed. Should it be? When you refer to virtual server configuration, do you mean server.conf?

Comment: Iptables are not necessary. Check files under /etc/apach2. There should be files for configuring server and ports they are listening at.

Comment: I added the /etc/apache2/port.conf file contents to my question.

Comment: It looks good, I think there is still a problem with DNS entries. Could you give me your address (ip and domain)  or use a dig command to check domain ip.

Comment: cazelequipment.com 50.45.48.99

Comment: It looks like your port forwarding doesnt work properly. Because i cant even connect with your host at port 22. I have checked that dns entries are fine. Maybe you are dealing wiht one of those problems : http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/27780-42-westell-7500-port-forwarding-working or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjEhw0Ozik4

Comment: I removed the server as a DMZ host and reapplied the port fording rules. I think I now have it working. Bless you!

Comment: Your server is now working like a charm. I dont mind if you check my answer as a solution.